# Logging the Https request at low level in c# .net

Tags: c#, logging, https

I am calling a service on HTTPS in C# using  System.ServiceModel.ClientBase (Auto generated code). It is working fine normally but sometimes the server receives the header but not the body.

How can I log what I am sending?

Comment: Can you post your code? Have you tried googling logging libraries?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to monitor outgoing requests.

Otherwise if you want to log the HTTPS in code you need to use Interceptors(like [Castle.DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/)) to intercept the calls that send requests and log the parameters there.

Comment: The request is HTTPS, so there is no way to see it on fiddler.

Comment: about Castle.DynamicProxy, I am not sure if it can intercept an HTTPS request, but anyways I prefer not to add any third party library to my project. .net is creating the request right? I want to see what it is sending

Comment: Yes you can. See http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/FirefoxHTTPS - just follow the instructions

Answer (score -1):

You should view what are you sending in the navigator on tab Lan.

Comment: what do you mean? the code is in production server and I want to log it, what is the tab lan?!